# import Vue from 'vue' Expected an identifier and insted saw 'import'. Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs, eslint

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJuyg.jpg)

```
import Vue from 'vue'                     
import Master from '@/components/layouts/Master'  
import router from '@/router/index'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router' 

window.eventBus = new Vue() 

Vue.config.productionTip = false 
Vue.use(VueRouter)  

new Vue({      
el: '#app',        
 router,  
components: {Master},  
template: '<Master/>'   
})
```

----> Error ocurs at first line or at line 3 on the image, Expected an identifier and instead saw 'import' import Vue from 'vue' <----

So this error shows from the moment i create the project via cmd, i tryed to crate the project with webpack without it installed all required stuff but still see this error and i dont get it, i would appreciate if someone can give me some direction to find the source of the problem. Thanks and have good day:)

Comment: It's a JSLint error, not an ESLint error. (Consider using ESLint instead, it's much more configurable and up-to-date with modern JS)

Comment: also gives an error in ESLint console, [undefined] Unexpected reserved word  import Vue from 'vue' , any idea what is the fix ?